# How to reschedule a task if it hasn't been running for more than 10 minutes?

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I have task:recursive_task which will schedule the same task to be executed 5 seconds later, but if for some reason this task crashes it needs to be rerun again. 
I catched nearly every scenario but you never know what will happen in the future.

I first made a repeated task:manage_tasks which checks the status of recursive_task and will check if it didn't run for a long time and if it was succesfully completed, but this didn't feel right. So how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try acks_late setting [CELERY_ACKS_LATE](http://ask.github.com/celery/configuration.html?highlight=acks_late#CELERY_ACKS_LATE), it will have the task messages be acknowledged after the task has been executed. With this you may be able to rerun your tasks more easily.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to take a look at python signals:

http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

```
import signal

# Set the signal handler and an alarm
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)
signal.alarm(900) # 15 miutes
# some_function()

signal.alarm(0)          # Disable the alarm
```

Where:

```
def handler(signum, frame):
    # do something
    sys.exit(1)
```

With signals, you can set the handler to be executed after any time, you want. Then it's a straight way to rerun your script through the handler.

Comment: wasn't me, but i took a look at your answer and it;s not quite what i needed for this question. In the end I solved it in the following way:    At the start of the task add a string to the cache "running" with expire time = 5 min, i have a cron job which checks every hour if there is the item in the cache which the tasks puts there everytime it starts, so if it doesnt start for more than 5 min there is no item in the cache anymore, and we start the task again.